# SQL statement with two sums and inner joins of three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, left-join

I have three tables in my mysql database

Table1 -> stockinfo

stock_id | stock_code | balance

```
    1 | stock_01 | 545
    2 | stock_02 | 105
    3 | stock_03 | 70
```

Table2 -> stock_in

stock_id | quantity | date_time

```
    1 |   50  | 2013-11-23
    1 |  250  | 2013-12-25
    1 |  300  | 2013-12-28
    2 |  100  | 2013-11-24
    2 |  150  | 2013-12-25
    3 |   30  | 2013-12-29
    3 |   40  | 2013-12-31
```

Table3 -> stock_out

stock_id | quantity | date_time

```
    1 |   20  | 2013-12-23
    1 |   35  | 2013-12-25
    2 |   70  | 2013-11-24
    2 |   75  | 2013-12-25
```

The first table stockinfo contains the stock information such as stock_code and balance, balance means the remaining quantity left for a stock.  stock_in table contains all the stock in of stock item with different dates and time.  stock_out tables contains all the stock out of stock item with different dates and time.  I want an output similar to the table below.  Total stock in and total stock out at a given date range.

Output : (I want to show total in and total out for the month of december 2013 only.)

stock_code | total_in | total_out | balance

```
     1 |  550  |   55   |  545
     2 |  150  |   75   |  105
     3 |   70  |   0    |  70
```

Here is my sql statement :

```
Select stock_code,
sum(case when stock_in.date_time >= '2013-12-01' and stock_in.date_time <= '2013-12-31' then stock_in.quantity else 0 end) as Total_In,
sum(case when stock_out.date_time >= '2013-12-01' and stock_out.date_time <= '2013-12-31' then stock_out.quantity else 0 end) as Total_Out, balance from stockinfo
left join stock_in on stockinfo.stock_id = stock_in.stock_id
left join stock_out on stockinfo.stock_id = stock_out.stock_id
group by stock_code
```

For the output, I am getting incorrect total for total_in and total_out.  I'm not sure which part I had it wrong.  If I only query the total_in and remove the total_out, it is working fine.  Likewise, if i only query the total_out and remove the total_in part, it is also working.  Please advice me which part I might have error in my SQL.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT s.stock_id, s.stock_code, IFNULL(si.Total_In, 0) Total_In, 
       IFNULL(so.Total_Out, 0) Total_Out, s.balance 
FROM stockinfo s
LEFT JOIN (SELECT si.stock_id, SUM(si.quantity) Total_In 
           FROM stock_in si 
           WHERE si.date_time BETWEEN '2013-12-01' AND '2013-12-31'
           GROUP BY si.stock_id
         ) si ON s.stock_id = si.stock_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT so.stock_id, SUM(so.quantity) Total_Out 
           FROM stock_out so 
           WHERE so.date_time BETWEEN '2013-12-01' AND '2013-12-31'
           GROUP BY so.stock_id
         ) so ON s.stock_id = so.stock_id
GROUP BY s.stock_id
```

Comment: hi shah.  It worked!!! :)  Thanks for your help.  Was stuck with this problem for several hours already.

Comment: hi shah, the sql worked.  Just wondering, what if I want to output 0 if there is value returned for the total_in and total_out.  Thanks.